# What is this grey status effect in Dark Souls Remastered?

Tags: dark-souls-remastered

I have a random status effect on my character.

[image]

I looked up the status effect symbols for Dark Souls Remastered, but the wiki doesn't have it. For reference, even if I remove all armor, rings, and weapons, it persists. Otherwise, I wear Marvelous Chester's set, and use a +15 Iaito, a +10 Fire Gargoyle's Halberd, the Grass Crest Shield, Havel's Ring, and the Ring of Steel Protection.

What is that grey oval symbol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on some Reddit threads ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/8mufti/weird_symbol_below_stamina_bar/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/8qynxy/wtf_is_this_status_icon/)), that symbol means you have a password set up for multiplayer.

One of the threads said it's the same for Dark Souls 3, so I checked [Dark Soul 3](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Status+Icons) status icon wiki. The icon is listed there:

[image]

Comment: Ahh! That's it, my friend needed help with Dunkstein and Slammough, in return he dropped some rare items to help me with the Knight's Honor achievement. Thanks!

Comment: what an awful icon lol